# Is there a built in function to expand a byte[] leaving zeros at the beginning?

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I've got this code

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(width).CopyTo(resultBytes, 0);
```

If the width is 12 it returns one byte not 4, is there a built in function to resize the array leaving 0's at the beginning
to output [0, 0, 0, 12] instead of [12].

Comment: int32 is the data type of width.

Comment: you should get 4 bytes then. have you tried it without the `CopyTo`?

Comment: it just returns [12, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: If 12 was the 4th byte, that wouldn't equal `12`. It would equal `49152`. Are you trying to switch Endianness?

Comment: @user3208848 what's the size of `resultBytes`?

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm writing the result to a file and then my other program reads it wrong like that. Some weird big number(incorrect probably that)

Comment: about 26, it's being written to a file afterwards.

Comment: You probably should look into [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It's likely written to the file in Little Endian.

Comment: where does your other program run, what type is it?

Comment: My other program is c# (I'm writing to a binary file)

Comment: how do you read and reconstruct the written value in the other program?

Comment: Have you tried using the [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead?

Comment: I use BitConvert.ToInt32(bytes, 0)

Comment: I'll see if System.IO.BinaryReader works

Comment: Is it written as `0C 00 00 00` or `00 00 00 0C` in your file? (assuming you are looking at it in hex)

Comment: It works, thank you for your help. With BinaryReader.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `width`? Bit converter just converts the type to an array of appropriate size. If you say

```
long  x = 1 ;
int   y = 2 ;
short z = 3 ;

byte[] x_bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x) ;
byte[] y_bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(y) ;
byte[] z_bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(z) ;
```

You'll get back 8-, 4- and 2-byte arrays, respectively. You can *cast* to the desired type:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( (int) x ) ;
```

And if you say something like

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(1) ;
```

You'll get back an array of 4 bytes: the type of an unsuffixed integer literal is the smallest type in which will fit, in order of preference: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`. If the literal is suffixed, it will be the type specified by the suffix (e.g., `1L` will give you an 8-byte `long`).

If you are converting an *expression*, such as:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( ((3*x + 2&y + z) << 3 ) & 5L ) ;
```

What gets converted is, of course, the type produced by evaluating the expression.

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast `width` to `int` in order to get 4 bytes, because the result of `GetBytes()` [is dependent on the type passed in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter_methods(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    BitConverter.GetBytes((int)width).CopyTo(resultBytes, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the simplest solution ever, but what about `Array.Reverse`:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(4).CopyTo(resultBytes, 0); // [4, 0, 0, 0]
Array.Reverse(resultBytes); // [0, 0, 0, 4]
```

Comment: What about if it was a big number though? It works in this case(your right).

Comment: @user3208848 and why it shouldn't work with big numbers? 100k zeroes and the number.